# Is it good practice for key-value store "rows" to be of completely different types?

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

We have a REST API, part of which displays a user's "catalog." A catalog is a list of products along with some overall catalog metadata (e.g. amount of money left).

We are at the stage of trying to add this metadata to catalog responses, but got stuck on our database design. The backing store is Amazon's DynamoDB, which is just a key-value store. Notably it supports something like a primary key ("hash") and secondary key ("range").

Currently our database entries look like:

```
{ customerId: "xxx", productId: "yyyy", productPrice: "zzz" }
```

We can more-or-less directly translate these into catalog entries, which yields a response of

```
{ products: [{ id: "yyyy", price: "zzz" }] }
```

But we want a response with metadata now, like

```
{ metadata: { moneyLeft: 5 }, products: [{ id: "yyyy", price: "zzz" }] }
```

The question is, **how do we store the metadata in our database**?

---

**Approach #1: Separate Databases**

Create a separate metadata table, with primary key `customerId`, and columns for all metadata properties. Then query both tables (two HTTP requests to DynamoDB), and assemble the results.

**Approach #2: Query Oriented**

Repurpose the current table to be specifically designed for this catalog-displaying query. It will have two types of rows, something like

```
{ customerId: "xxx", productId: "yyyy", productPrice: "zzz", type: "product" }
{ customerId: "xxx", moneyLeft: 5, type: "metadata" }
```

(although a bit more robust). Then we could do a query to select all rows from the table with `customerId = xxx`, and in our server code transform them into the desired response by switching on the `type` property.

---

I'm leaning toward approach #2, because it seems like approach #1 is still stuck in relational-DB thinking, and it would involve two DB calls (= HTTP requests). But it's just so weird, I'm not sure that's a good idea. Maybe there's a third approach? I imagine the real answer is "you should use a document database," but we're pretty committed to DynamoDB by this point -_-.

Answer (score 0):

What is the range key of the table? I assume the hash key is the customerId...
Overall when thinking about NoSQL solutions I find my self thinking "what am I going to query"
If your query will always be "query all items with customerId = XXX" then I think it is bad design to slip another "metadata" item there. 
More robust and wasteful approach is to concatenate the metadata into all items, but that has drawbacks on it's own in terms of update. (I wouldn't recommend it either)
I think that even if it sounds like a relational approach, in your scenario I'd stick with another table.
Furthermore, by partially understanding your database, I still think it would make sense to query the meta data of a user without actually querying his catalog.